# Quickest and easiest way to get node to import JSX files in 2022?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to create a super simple express view engine that will render React/JSX component files. I am not concerned with hydration right now, I just want the markup to render.

Here is my express code:

```js
import * as ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'

app.engine('jsx', async function (filePath, options, callback) {
    const component = await import(filePath)

    return callback(null, ReactDOMServer.renderToString(component))
})
```

When I try and view the page in the browser, I get this error:

> TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".jsx"

I boot up the server using `NODE_ENV=local nodemon index.js`

How do I get node to import JSX files? Is there a simple way of doing this without requiring 1000 dependencies + babel?

Is there a simple solution to this that will do the JSX import super fast?

Tried reading up on babel etc. and it was either super slow or didn't work properly.

Comment: You will probably need babel for that

Comment: Typescript can compile JS(x) files as well as TS(x) files, so that might be the simplest way..    And if you want super fast compiles ESBuild is another options ->  https://esbuild.github.io/

Comment: I just ended up using `babel-node` with the automatic runtime and it seems to work now.